# structured data for long list of computers

Tags: structured-data

I have a HTML table of about 600 desktop computers models, with their specs.

I will make the table sortable using an off the shelf Jquery component.

I'm new to structured data. Is it worth tagging each table cell as to make each product row a structured data product?

Comment: I am thinking that this page would download rather slow due to size already. If you add mark-up, it would be that much slower.

Comment: You could just opt to host it in Googles cloud sheets and then embed it on the page.

Comment: @closetnoc: the Excel file is 267KB. Let's say the HTML table is 1.5MB. Adding markup would perhaps take it to 2MB?

Comment: It is okay for some pages to be rather long. I am just not sure you want this type of page to be so long. There are other techniques such as AJAX that can really help. I am not an expert on AJAX at all. But I do know that it is simple to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of putting the table data into a database, and using drop down boxes to display only a subset of the data. Don't know how to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this listing of computer models has a commercial purpose. Then anytime you will not be able to go around without Google Shopping. And G Shopping will force you to provide the data feed of your products. This data feed should be a csv file. Then G recommends to implement structured data into product pages, so it can validate products from your shopping feed with products on your page. At least at this moment your wish of structured data becomes a need.

Dealing with such amount of data i would recommend to use JSON-LD for products, with following approach:

1. Look at the shopping feed specifications

   - https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188494
   - https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/1344057
   - https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160588
2. Adjust your products table to go conform with G-Shopping
3. Generate JSON-LD from your products table

   Possible approaches:

   - https://www.w3.org/2013/csvw/wiki/CSV-LD
   - https://github.com/gkellogg/csv-ld
   - http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm
4. Implement your JSON-LD snippet into category and product pages. Use on the page where your list all computer models something like

   - https://schema.org/SomeProducts
   - https://schema.org/AggregateOffer

Comment: Fantastic help Evgeniy. Thank you. I wonder if Magento can help here?